# Arranging 3 numbers in ascending order - function not working as expected

Tags: c, arrays

As part of a bigger problem I have to sort 3 numbers in ascending order.
A simple enough task, but for some reason I'm not getting the expected result.
Using arrays is not allowed.
Please let me know if you can tell what the problem is. I've been racking my
brains and I just can't see it :<
Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void order(int a, int b);

int main(void)
{       
    int x, y, z;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);

    order(x, y);
    order(x, z);
    order(y, z);

    printf("%d %d %d", x, y, z);

    return 0;
}

void order(int a, int b)
{
    int inter;

    if(a > b)   
    { 
        inter = a;
        a = b;
        b = inter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the numbers x, y, and z by value. So the *swap* you do in order() will not reflect in main().

Instead pass the address of the variables and modify them so that original variables in main() reflect the changes you did in order():

```
#include <stdio.h>

void order(int *a, int *b);

int main(void)
{       
    int x, y, z;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);

    order(&x, &y);
    order(&x, &z);
    order(&y, &z);

    printf("%d %d %d", x, y, z);

    return 0;
}

void order(int *a, int *b)
{
    int inter;

    if(*a > *b)   
    { 
        inter = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = inter;
    }
}
```

Comment: @lulia Elena you may want to look into how the pointers work. Cheers.

Comment: @lulia Elena Yeah, that should suffice for the time being and your information is perfectly correct.

Comment: @Kraken Yes, indeed. I haven't studied those yet, actually, so I'm still a bit confused. I get that a pointer 'points to' the address of a variable, and it makes sense to me that by using pointers to the numbers in my program I would actually change the values located at the 'pointed' address. But I'm still a bit in the dark as to why using the numbers per say fails to do the job. What exactly happens? I assume that the values get interchanged inside the order function, but for some reason this change isn't reflected when printing them out.

Comment: @Kraken Does the printf function access a variable's value by looking at it's address? And are variables modified within a function stored at a different address than the original, unless otherwise specified (i.e. by using pointers)? Hope this questions make some sense ^^;

Comment: @lulia Elena Think of this as the following, when you pass by value, i.e. using no pointer, then the copies of the variables are made inside the function. Hence you may pass the value `a` and `b` to the function by `function(a,b)` but inside the function, the values are copied into new variables and all the operations are done on the copied data. Hence your original variables remain the way they were prior to the function call.

Comment: @lulia When you pass the x,y, & z the values are *copied*. So the changes you do with the copy has no relation to the values in main(). But you pass the pointer to the variables, the pointers are 
still passed by value, but you can change still the values *pointed to* by the pointers.

Comment: @lulia Elena Now consider if you pass the address of the pointers, then even though the address will be copied inside the function call, but since we are not changing the address variables, but the value stored at those addresses, hence the change is depicted on the outside of the function after the function call.